# Can't find the good Cygwin shell executable

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, cygwin

I am working on Windows 7 and I need Cygwin for my project.

I am trying to launch the Cygwin terminal from a Java programm and then write command lines but my problem is that I can't find the right executabe to launch .

I have tried to launch the mintty.exe and the bash.exe but the commands like ls or cd aren't known by the terminal.

Is there another cygwin shell executable on the cygwin\bin that works ?

Comment: How exactly  did you launch `mintty`?

Comment: I have launched it like this
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe");
    Process p = pb.start();

Answer (score 1):

#### When I launch mintty or bash commands like ls or cd don't work

You need to launch mintty as a login shell (by adding a single `-` to the command line):

```
C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -
```

This is the command that is run from the Cygwin64 Terminal shortcut.

Target `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -`

[image]

---

> **INVOCATION**
>
> If a program name is supplied on the command line, this is executed with any additional arguments given. Otherwise, mintty looks for a shell to execute in the SHELL environment variable. If that is not set, it reads the user’s default shell setting from /etc/passwd. As a last resort, it falls back to /bin/sh.
>
> **If a single dash is specified instead of a program name, the shell is invoked as a login shell.**

Source [Manual Reference Pages  - mintty (1)](http://mintty.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1065/trunk/docs/mintty.1.html)

Comment: I have used your tip and a cygwin shell opened, but How can I, in my programm, after the shell opened, write in it via my programm ?

Comment: That's a different question and should be asked on [so], but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can refer to this question for context.